# NodeJS child_process throws error when SIGINT happens

Tags: javascript, node.js, process, ecmascript-6

If you run this code and press `Ctrl-C` in the console, the program should exit after the current iteration of the loop is over, not immediately.

But when `child_process.exec` sees `SIGINT`, it throws an error. I don't want that to happen, instead the child process should always run to completion even in the presence of `SIGINT`, so that I can terminate the program when I want (in this case, at the end of the current `while` loop), as shown in my `process.on('SIGINT', ...)` handler

(This code uses ES6 async/await. The `pify` module here is just used to turn `child_process.exec` into a `Promise` so you can `await` it.)

```
import childprocess from 'child_process'
import pify from 'pify'

const exec = pify(childprocess).exec

let willStop = false;

(async () => {
  try {
    while (!willStop) {
      console.log('start process')
      await exec('curl http://ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/5MB.zip >/dev/null 2>&1')
      console.log('finish process')
    }
    console.log('stopped')
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e.message)
  }
})()

process.on('SIGINT', () => {
  willStop = true
  console.log('will stop')
})
```

This is what I expect to see (`^C` is where `Ctrl-C` is entered)

```
start process
finish process
start process
^C
will stop
finish process
stopped
```

This is what I actually see

```
start process
finish process
start process
^C
will stop
Command failed: curl http://ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/5MB.zip >/dev/null 2>&1
```

How can I change the code so the child process doesn't terminate immediately when seeing a `SIGINT`?